# Cart only changes color of the first item of each game

Tags: javascript

I have this function that add's to my cart html, and its working fine. But when i add two of the same Item i get an error(only changes color in the first of each same item).
The console.log(changeBackgroundColor); console.log(changeColorText); gets only the first div of each game.

[image]

```
   const addToCart = function () {
      getJSON('games.json', function (err, data) {
        var cartBets = document.getElementById('cart-bets');
        if (err === null) {
          console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
        } else {
          let html = '';
          regexPrice = data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].price;
          totalPrice += regexPrice;
          let newTotalPrice = data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].price
            .toFixed(2)
            .replace('.', ',');
          html += '<div class="bar-side-cart">';
          html += '<div class="side-by-side">';
          html +=
            '<div class="menu-thrash-save"><i onclick="deleteItemCart(this)" value="' +
            data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].price +
            '" class="far fa-trash-alt" src="img/thrash-can.jfif" width=15 alt="Thrash"></i> 
             </div>';
          html +=
            '<div data-style="cart-thrash-side-bar-' +
            data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].type +
            '" class="bets-backgroundcolor-lotos-container"></div>';
          html += '<div class="top-by-top">';
          html += '<p class="cart-right-text">' + totalNumbers + '</p>';
          html += '<div class="side-by-side">';
          html +=
            '<div data-style="cart-text-thrash-' +
            data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].type +
            '" class="bets-color-lotos-container">' +
            data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].type +
            '</div>';
          html += '<div class="cart-money">R$ ' + newTotalPrice + '</div>';
          html += '</div>';
          cartBets.innerHTML += html;
          var changeBackgroundColor = document.querySelector(
            '[data-style="cart-thrash-side-bar-' +
              data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].type +
              '"]'
          );
          changeBackgroundColor.style.backgroundColor =
            data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].color;
          var changeColorText = document.querySelector(
            '[data-style="cart-text-thrash-' +
              data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].type +
              '"]'
          );
          changeColorText.style.color = data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].color;
          console.log(changeBackgroundColor);
          console.log(changeColorText);
          getCartTotal();
        }
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelector()` only returns the first matched element. Try using `document.querySelectorAll()` with a loop:

```js
var changeBackgroundColor = document.querySelectorAll(
  '[data-style="cart-thrash-side-bar-' +
    data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].type +
    '"]'
);

changeBackgroundColor.forEach(
  element => element.style.backgroundColor =
  data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].color
);
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! (Btw, works fine with querySelector too)

Comment: What do you mean it works with `querySelector`? You won't get multiple nodes with `querySelector()`.

Comment: Worked with querySelector + forEach, with querySelectorAll + forEach works too, just a curiosity

Comment: Maybe you had a loop outside of `querySelector` and changed the element in a why that would make it no longer match the selector. That way, a loop and querySelector could affect multiple nodes. I can't think of any other way.